# WPF disabling the window close button via MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to disable the close button on a window via MVVM

I realise that you can do this in the view (window) CS code by stating

```
public Window()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(Window_Closing);
}

void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

However I would like to keep it consistent and try to do this is the MVVM.

Thanks

Comment: why you do it like that? You have a close button and you disable it's function,so, why not make it hidden?

Comment: Just because I am firing a background thread so I need to stop the user from firing events as the hread is happening, once the thread has finished, of couse I will enable it back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `Closing` method with a variable from ViewModel.

```
void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = (this.DataContext as MyViewModel).ProcessWorking;
}
```

In your ViewModel (`MyViewModel`) add a property `ProcessWorking` :

```
public Boolean ProcessWorking
{
    get { return this.processWorking; }
}
```

and in your method of background thread, just modify `processWorking`

```
private Boolean processWorking;

private void MyBackgroundThread()
{
    this.processWorking = true;

    // do your process

    this.processWorking = false;
}
```

You can add a `RaisePropertyChange()` when you modify `this.processWorking` if you want to show somewhere of your UI the state of the background process.

Answer (score 3):

It's a strange demand. If you have a closing button,why you disable it's func. But you can realize it with mvvm like this:

add two ref:
- Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll
- System.Windows.Interactivity.dll

add two xmlns:

```
 xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
 xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

create trigger to window:

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:control="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
        xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="WindowsClosing"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid >

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

edit viewmodel,and creat closing func:

```
 public void WindowsClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks this looks good. Will and try and mark as answer sometime today. Its because I am firing a background thread so I need to stop the user from firing events as the thread is happening, once the thread has finished, of couse I will enable it back

Comment: @user3428422 I see now! btw , Interaction need .net4.0 at least.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `ResizeMode` of Window or you can use it by using Window API use of Window API mentioend [Here](http://winsharp93.wordpress.com/2009/07/21/wpf-hide-the-window-buttons-minimize-restore-and-close-and-the-icon-of-a-window/)